# How to insert and add elements in a combo box in Excel through Python?

Tags: python, vba, python-2.7, excel

I wrote a Python code to make a workbook with `n` sheets in it.For each sheet it has two columns.I am writing the values of these 2 columns through Python.For each of the values in column A I add an element to the combo box.

Image given below.

[image]

The problem is I am manually inserting a combo box to each of the sheets and then written a macro (on workbook open) for each sheet to insert values of column A in the combo box.My questions are:

1. Is there a way to insert and add elements in a combo box to each sheet in Excel **using Python** ?
2. Is there a way to add elements in a combo box of each sheet by writing a macro for the whole workbook because it is not feasible to write macro for each sheet.

**EDIT::** I am accessing xlrd to take values and xlwt to write it in excel.

Here is my **complete code**

```
import xlrd,xlwt


file_loc = "C:\\Users\\Badhe\\Desktop\\stocks1.xlsx"

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_loc)

a = workbook.sheet_names()   

temp = xlwt.Workbook()        #write in this workbook

for stock_no in range(0,workbook.nsheets):
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(stock_no)

    print "\n"+a[stock_no]+"\n"

    sh = temp.add_sheet(a[stock_no])    #add new sheet to workbook

    sh.write(0,0,"Strike")
    sh.write(0,1,"Payoff")

    X = sheet.cell_value(4,11);j = 4

    for rows in range(4,sheet.nrows-4):
        c = sheet.cell_value(j,8); p = sheet.cell_value(j,13)

        diff = sheet.cell_value(4,11)-sheet.cell_value(3,11)

        diff = float(diff)

        if(c != u'-'and p != u'-'):

            c=float(c);p=float(p)

            Xp = X - diff ; Xc = X + diff
            pl = sheet.cell_value(j-1,14); cl = sheet.cell_value(j+1,9)

            if(cl != u'-' and pl != u'-'):
                cl=float(cl);pl=float(pl)

                sh.write(rows,0,X)
                sh.write(rows,1,c+p-cl-pl-diff)

        j = j + 1
        X = X + diff

temp.save("C:\\Users\\Badhe\\Desktop\\test1.xlsm")
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: With your code, we'll be able to help you better.  Are you accessing the Win32 com component or via another means?